# php does not insert current timestamp into mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql table has a column DatePosted with the Datatype as `TIMESTAMP`.

I am trying to insert the current TIMESTAMP into the table using PHP. However the below code does not seem to work i get  `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Is the format wrong how do i get the current timestamp to be inserted in mysql

TIMESTAMP.php file

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

echo date("j of F Y, \a\\t g.i a", time());

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cfv_timestamp (DatePosted) VALUES ('".date("j F Y, \a\\t g.i a", time())."' )");
```

.

```
CREATE TABLE `cfv_timestamp (
  `DatePosted` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Why don't you use `NOW()` ? ... `mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cfv_timestamp (DatePosted) VALUES (NOW())");`

Comment: Or `INSERT INTO cfv_timestamp (DatePosted) VALUES (DEFAULT)` or even `INSERT INTO cfv_timestamp () VALUES ()` since DatePosted has a default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: @BillKarwin i did not want to use the Default CURRENTTIMESTAMP since i wanted the timezone of America/Los_Angeles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check mysql Timestamp [format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html) and change yours.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO cfv_timestamp (DatePosted) 
    VALUES ('".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time())."' )");
```

Also you could set default value for Timestamp type [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)